# JavaScript regex multiline replace

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to replace this

```
@#@ visibility="hidden" @#@
{% include "grid-overlay.njk" %}

@#@ contentPartial="promo/tru-report/"
class="q-promo-container promo--hidden"
expires="2023-04-30T17:00:00Z"@#@
{% include "promo-banner.njk" %}
```

with this

```
{% set visibility="hidden" %}
{% include "grid-overlay.njk" %}

{% set contentPartial="promo/tru-report/" %}
{% set class="q-promo-container promo--hidden" %}
{% set expires="2023-04-30T17:00:00Z" %}
{% include "promo-banner.njk" %}
```

I can find all matches using this regex

```
regex = /@#@\s*([a-zA-Z0-9-_/\.=:"'\s]+)\s*@#@/gim;
```

but I'm not sure how to use the replace function to get the desired output. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mention JavaScript in the title but this looks nothing like it. What (templating) language is this?

Comment: Seems to be [tag:nunjucks].

Comment: It's Nunjucks, but I'm using JavaScript to convert a bunch of old code to Nunjucks syntax. I was able to resolve this particular issue using a replacer function.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I figured it out by using a [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement).

```
function replacer(match, p1, offset, string) {
  var variablesArray = p1.split(/"\s+/gi);
  variablesArray = variablesArray.filter(n => n);
  var statements = variablesArray.map(function (statement) {
    return `{% set ${statement}" %}`;
  });
  statements = statements.join("\n");
  return statements;
}

oldContent = newContent;
regex = /@#@\s*([a-zA-Z0-9-_/\.=:"'\s]+)\s*@#@/gim;
newContent = oldContent.replace(regex, replacer);
```